# How to update a Angular Reactive form with php backend

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

please, can you help me with the following situation? I try to update a form with reactive forms for a few weeks and I can't find any solution to work. I am so desperate because I know that I am at a small step to succeed. Here's what I've tried so far:

TS code

```
const routeParams = this.route.snapshot.params;
console.log(routeParams.id_medic);
this.addForm = this. formBuilder. group({
Name: [''],
Telephone: [''],
Email: [''],
Hospital: [''],
City: [''],
});
this.doctorsService
.getMedicById(routeParams.id_medic)
.subscribe((medic: any) => {
this.medic = medic;
this.addForm.patchValue(medic);
});
}

editMedic() {
this.mediciService
.updateMedic(this.addForm.value)
.subscribe(() => {
this.location.back();
this.toastr.success('Medic Updated');
});
}
```

SERVICE TS Code

```
updateMedic(info) {
return this.http.post('https://site/api/uMedic.php', info);
}
```

Html code

```
<form  [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="editMedic()">
<input type="text" formControlName="Name" placeholder="Name">
......................................
</form>
```

PHP

```
`<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
include "db.php";
$sql = "UPDATE Doctors SET
Name='$data->Name',  Telephone='$data->Telephone', Email ='$data->Email', Hospital='$data->Hospital', City='$data->City'
WHERE id_medic = $data->id_medic";
$qry = $conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();
?>`
```

Any suggestion would be extraordinary! Thank you so much!

Comment: The new form value object you pass to `patchValue` should have the same keys as your `FormGroup` does. If not, then you can get individual form controls and call `setValue` on each returned form control

Comment: Thank you @Teedeez ! The keys are the same, i've checked so many times...

Comment: `echo $sql` query and run your mysql server and see what was the result

Comment: `console.log(this.addForm.value);` your form value and see what form data you send

Comment: Thank you @BhargavChudasama ! I did a console log, and the new values are correct! This is the query: UPDATE Doctors SET Name='', Telephone='', Email ='', Hospital='', City='' WHERE id_medic =

Comment: could you share the console.log(medic) after subscribing it so we can see what response is coming on that service call.

Comment: @AlinMB is sure that your backend service working

Comment: @PujanShah : This is the console.log(medic): e-medic.component.ts:51 {Name: "Alin", Telephone: "073000000", Email: "b.alin@ymail.com", Hospital: "Oncology", City: "Bucharest"}. In console log, i have this error now: ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://puve.site.ro/api/uMedic.php", ok: false, …}

Comment: There is no `id_medic` for update your record @AlinMB

Comment: Please share stackblitz link with code.

Comment: i have inserted the `id_medic` and still not working.. @BhargavChudasama

Comment: you tried with your query in mysql server @AlinMB

Comment: You should call the API and update your form group in `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` and not in the constructor

Comment: The API and the form is called from ngOnInit, not in the constructor @Teedeez !

Comment: Can you try these? **1:** When you are creating your form group, replace `['']` with `this.formBuilder.control('')`, **2:** call your API and update the form group in `ngAfterViewInit`, **3:** use `setValue` instead of `patchValue`

Comment: Now is working perfectly fine, the values are updated in database, but i have this error: core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://puve.fabc.ro/api/uMedic.php", ok: false, …}

Comment: Everything is working fine. Thank you all for your help. I put this code in my service.ts: `  updateMedic(info) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    const httpOptions = {
      headers
    };

    return this.http.post('https://puve.site.ro/api/uMedic.php', info, {responseType: 'text'});
  }`